# Arduino Stepper Motor pointer in a Class is not working

Tags: c++, class, arduino, stepper

I created a class to manage commands thru serial port and i am using a stepper motor but when i am trying to use step function is not working.
I declare an object in arduino file and i used pointer of stepper object to wotk inside class. testing it, setSpeed method works fine but when i try to use step method, i got segmentation fault on compiling action. 
Stepper motor library is working ok, i already did some test and motor works fine but when i tried to use it in a class with pointers is not working.

main file

```
    #include "ClassTest.h"

    ClassTest test;

    Stepper myStepper1 = Stepper(200, 8, 9, 10, 11);

    void setup() {
        test.SetupMotor(&myStepper1);  
    }
    void loop() {
        test.MoveMotor('Motor1',200);  
    }
```

ClassTest.h

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Stepper.h"

class ClassTest
{
  public:
    ClassTest();
    void SetupMotor(Stepper* step);
    void MoveMotor(String ,int );
  private:
    Stepper* _myStepper1;
};
```

ClassTest.cpp

```
void ClassTest::SetupMotor(Stepper* step)
{
    _myStepper1=step;
        _myStepper1->setSpeed(200);
}

void ClassTest::MoveMotor(String motor,int stepCount)
{
        // i am getting an issue on compiling time about segmentation fault
    _myStepper1->step(200);

}
```

I tried many things but not sure why is not working yet, any help???
Thanks!!

Comment: sorry, wrong line, fixed it

Comment: What does you `void loop()` source code look like in main file, is it empty?

Comment: It is not empty but i did not included in explanation  since i got segmentation fault on compiling or uploading to arduino but in loop function says test.MoveMotor('motor1',200);

Comment: Shouldn't ```test.MoveMotor('Motor1',200); ``` be ```test.MoveMotor("Motor1",200); ```? Double quotes instead of single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your error. The following code compiles in Arduino IDE:

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Stepper.h"

class ClassTest
{
  public:
    ClassTest() = default;
    void SetupMotor(Stepper* step);
    void MoveMotor(String, int );
  private:
    Stepper* _myStepper1;
};

void ClassTest::SetupMotor(Stepper* step)
{
  _myStepper1 = step;
  _myStepper1->setSpeed(200);
}

void ClassTest::MoveMotor(String motor, int stepCount)
{
  _myStepper1->step(200);

}

ClassTest test;

Stepper myStepper1 = Stepper(200, 8, 9, 10, 11);

void setup() {
  test.SetupMotor(&myStepper1);
}
void loop() {
  test.MoveMotor("Motor1", 200);
}
```

Comment: correct, issue was on Serial port, i was writing and reading from it and i was getting a segmentation fault after a few tests using this code, i guess overflow of serial port, not sure but it is working now. Thanks!